# Get instagram user analytics by username

Tags: php, curl, instagram, instagram-api

I want to get the instagram user analytics, i. e. to get the time sheet with count of followers and followings.
Is there any way to get the data from instagram api?
Or Is there other sites that I can get the analytics automatically with PHP?

Answer (score 1):

No analytics API from Instagram yet. we have to search users by user id.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users

In the api response the user json contains "counts" for followers, following and medias.

If you just has usernames with you then first search the users from user name by https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_search; get ids from them and use above API.

To generate the trend; we have to make the API calls daily, for all users!
very costly, but there is no direct API available from Insta yet.

However, FB just released new API for user insights under graph api.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user#insights
this works only for instagram business accounts though. and you need the access tokens on behalf of the account you want insights for.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019-06 you can only access analytics (they call it *insights* at FB) for your own profile. You can't access insights of other user profile.

For example, let's get your own **followers_count**.

```
graph.facebook.com
  /{your_facebookPage_id}/insights?metric=followers_count&period=day
```

You get this JSON as response:

```
{
  "insights": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "follower_count",
        "period": "day",
        "values": [
          {
            "value": 2,
            "end_time": "2019-06-24T07:00:00+0000"
          },
          {
            "value": 0,
            "end_time": "2019-06-25T07:00:00+0000"
          }
        ],
        "title": "Follower Count",
        "description": "Total number of unique accounts following this profile",
        "id": "{your_facebookPage_id}/insights/follower_count/day"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/{your_facebookPage_id}/insights?access_token=...&pretty=0&metric=follower_count&period=day&since=1561115213&until=1561288013",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/{your_facebookPage_id}/insights?access_token=...&pretty=0&metric=follower_count&period=day&since=1561460815&until=1561633615"
    }
  },
  "id": "{your_facebookPage_id}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this API

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{ig-user-id}?fields=business_discovery.username(ig-username){followers_count,media_count,media{comments_count,like_count}}&access_token={access-token}
```

Of course, it does not provide full analytics, but you can get a lot of information about users through username. And response will be:

```
{
  "business_discovery": {
    "followers_count": 267793,
    "media_count": 1205,
    "media": {
      "data": [
        {
          "comments_count": 50,
          "like_count": 5841,
          "id": "17858843269216389"
        },
        {
          "comments_count": 11,
          "like_count": 2998,
          "id": "17894036119131554"
        },
        {
          "comments_count": 28,
          "like_count": 3644,
          "id": "17894449363137701"
        },
        {
          "comments_count": 43,
          "like_count": 4943,
          "id": "17844278716241265"
        },
        {
          "comments_count": 60,
          "like_count": 9347,
          "id": "17899363132086521"
        },
        {
          "comments_count": 63,
          "like_count": 6913,
          "id": "17893114378137541"
        },
        {
          "comments_count": 16,
          "like_count": 2791,
          "id": "17886057709171561"
        },
        {
          "comments_count": 15,
          "like_count": 3895,
          "id": "17856337633208377"
        },
      ],
    },
    "id": "17841401441775531"
  },
  "id": "17841405976406927"
}
```